# SSAS Grand Total is wrong because get value from Calculated member

Tags: excel, ssas, mdx

I have 2 Calculated Member AVG Weekly Percentage and AVG Monthly Percentage.
For weekly the Result is Good 
[image]

And for AVG Monthly Percentage there is error on Grand Total because there is the addition of a grand total of AVG Weekly percent.

[image]

the real result AVG(99.83%+85.59%+99.80%+100%+100%+100%) = 97.54%

but the Result from Cube (AVG(99.83%+85.59%+99.80%+100%+100%+100%  + 100% (from weekly grand total)) = 97.89%

For AVG Weekly Percentage

```
  IIF(
    isempty([Measures].[Actual Quantity MTD]) or [Measures].[Actual Quantity MTD]=0 or isempty([Measures].[Original Plan Quantity  MTD])   , null ,
    IIF([Measures].[Original Plan Quantity MTD] =0 or 
 isempty([Measures].[Original Plan Quantity MTD]),null,   
    IIF( 
    ([Measures].[Actual Quantity MTD]-[Measures].[Original Plan Quantity MTD]) > 0 , 1 ,[Measures].[Actual Quantity MTD]/ [Measures].[Original Plan Quantity MTD]
```

and for AVG monthly Percentage

```
AVG ( 
DESCENDANTS([PSL Scenario].[PSL Scenario Description])*
DESCENDANTS([Plant].[Plant])*
DESCENDANTS([Finish Date].[Calendar],[Finish Date].[Calendar].[Month Year]) 
, AVG(([Finish Date].[Calendar].CURRENTMEMBER.CHILDREN), [Measures].[AVG Weekly Percentage]))
```

What do i miss?

Comment: I dont think you can do average of an average as you mention: AVG(99.83%+85.59%+99.80%+100%+100%+100%) = 97.54%

Answer (score 0):

You may have to exclude the 'weekly grand total' (as you call it) from the calculation.

I have had situations like this, where I tell the calculation to only use values if they are from the leaf level (or a particular level) of the hierarchy. Can you do this?

Comment: I cannot do this because the Monthly Calculation get value from AVG(Weekly), is there any idea you can suggest ?

Comment: It is possible you want to read about 'Visual Totals'. Have a read of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145527.aspx and see if that looks like it will help. I think it might identify your issue, but please comment again if you're still stuck.